# Rails - select extra field from has_many :through model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have the following structure

```
class Project
  has_many :teammates
  has_many :users, :through => :teammates
end

class Teammate
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end

class User
  has_many :teammates
  has_many :users, :through => :teammates
end
```

I added an extra field to the joining model: teammates -> **pending:boolean**

What I want to do is display a project including users with the boolean to know whether or not each user is still pending or not.

EDIT: the query looks like this:

```
Project.includes(:users).find(params[:id])
```

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
class Project
  has_many :teammates

  # I tried this
  has_many :users, :through => :teammates, :select => 'users.*, teammates.*'
  # ERROR: Unknown key: :select

  # And this
  has_many :users, -> { select("users.*, teammates.pending") }, through: :teammates
  # ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "teammates"
end
```

Comment: And what's your problem?

Comment: The problem is that when I do the query, only the user gets fetched. The boolean is not part of the result.

Comment: What does your query look like?

Comment: It will not fix your problem, but `has_many :teammates` is missing in `class User`.

Comment: You're right (I edited the original question)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
@project = Project.find(params[:id])
@project.teammates.each do |teammate|
  # an example provided to show that you have access to `pending` field as well as all users fields:
  teammate.pending # pending field
  teammate.user # all user fields
end
```